# What can I use instead?

Tags: python

I was looking at the following code but I need other way to substitute the following elements:

**-=** and  **.join(result)** .

```
def int_to_roman(input):
    if not isinstance(input, type(1)):
        raise TypeError( "expected integer, got %s" % type(input))
    if not 0 < input < 4000:
        raise ValueError("Argument must be between 1 and 3999")
    ints = (1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1)
    nums = ('M', 'CM', 'D', 'CD','C', 'XC','L','XL','X','IX','V','IV','I')
    result = []

    for i in range(len(ints)):
        count = int(input / ints[i])
        result.append(nums[i] * count)
        input -= ints[i] * count
    return ''.join(result)
```

Thank You

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Note that using input as a variable is a bad idea, as input is a builtin, but you have bigger issues (like actually having an answerable question) first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea **why** you want to do this, but here goes:

Replace this line:

```
input -= ints[i] * count
```

With:

```
input = input - (ints[i] * count)
```

And `return ''.join(result)`

With:

```
s = ""
for i in result:
   s = s + i + " "
s = s.strip()
return s
```

Comment: Thank You very much for your help. Have a nice Weekend.